# Calling width(), height(), size() or rect() inside subclass of QWidget ends with segfault

Tags: c++, qt, size, segmentation-fault, qwidget

I have a problem with `QWidget`'s `width()`, `height()`, `size()` or `rect()` function; when it is called it gets a segfault. It is Qt 4.7.

Here is the header of the problematic class:

```
class PlotCanvas : public QWidget
{ 
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e);
    uint64_t smallestDiv();
    uint64_t longestLength();
    void drawGrid(QPainter * painter);
    QVector<Plot*> plots;
    int calculateHeight() const;
    int calculateWidth() const;
    uint32_t cursorPosition;
public:
    PlotCanvas(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) 
    {
        setStyleSheet("background-color: black");
        setAutoFillBackground(true);
        setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
        setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
        update();
    }
    void addPlot(Plot * plot);
    int getDivCount();
};
```

and actual segfaulting code:

```
int PlotCanvas::getDivCount()
{
   QRect bounds = rect(); //segfaults
   qDebug() << bounds.size().width();
   qDebug() << bounds.size().height();
   return 10;
}
```

traced into Qt's `qrect.h`:

```
inline int QRect::width() const
{ return  x2 - x1 + 1; } //this line finally kills it
```

Which seems like there is something not initialized properly inside `QWidget`, but I have no clue what, because as you can see I am not really changing initialization of `QWidget` that much.

`PlotCanvas` widget resides in subclass of `QAbstractScrollArea` (which is not implemented yet, so it is just plain `QAbstractScrollArea`:

```
class PlotCanvasScrollArea : public QAbstractScrollArea
{
public:
    PlotCanvasScrollArea(QWidget * parent = 0) : QAbstractScrollArea(parent) 
    {

    }
};
```

I just need to determine size of `QWidget` painting area, because I am plotting in transition diagram and I need to know how many time divisions will fit into current widget size, because obviously application window is resizable.

EDIT:

Code where `PlotCanvas` is constructed:

```
Board(QString & name) : name(name)
{
    hbox = new QHBoxLayout();
    commonKnobGroup = new QGroupBox("Common settings:");
    commonKnobGroup->setMinimumWidth(190);
    commonKnobGroup->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum));
    commonKnobs = new CommonKnobs(commonKnobGroup);
    hsplitter = new QSplitter();
    plotGroupBox = new QGroupBox("Measurement plots:", hsplitter);
    settingsGroupBox = new QGroupBox("Plot settings:", hsplitter);
    plotSplitter = new QSplitter();
    plotHbox = new QHBoxLayout();
    plotHbox->addWidget(plotSplitter);
    plotGroupBox->setLayout(plotHbox);
    settingsVLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    plotNamesColumn = new QListWidget(plotSplitter);
    scrollArea = new PlotCanvasScrollArea(plotSplitter);
    //scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
    plotsCanvas = new PlotCanvas();
    scrollArea->setViewport(plotsCanvas);
    scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
    specializedKnobGroup = new QGroupBox("Probe settings:");
    plotSettings = new QStackedWidget(specializedKnobGroup);
    settingsVLayout->addWidget(commonKnobGroup);
    settingsVLayout->addWidget(specializedKnobGroup);
    settingsGroupBox->setLayout(settingsVLayout);
    hbox->addWidget(hsplitter);
    setLayout(hbox);
    connect(plotNamesColumn, SIGNAL(currentItemChanged(QListWidgetItem *, QListWidgetItem *)), this,
            SLOT(changePageNames(QListWidgetItem*, QListWidgetItem*)));
    connect(commonKnobs, SIGNAL(scaleUpdated()), plotsCanvas, SLOT(update()));

};
```

EDIT2:
Complete stacktrace:

```
#0  0x000000010000b9ac in QWidget::rect() const at /Volumes/Data/shinji/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtGui/qwidget.h:1007
#1  0x000000010000b454 in PlotCanvas::getDivCount() ()
#2  0x000000010000ab39 in Board::getDivCount() ()
#3  0x0000000100009fbc in CommonKnobs::updateScaleByBeginEnd() ()
#4  0x00000001000015b4 in CommonKnobs::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) ()
#5  0x0000000100d09b66 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) ()
#6  0x000000010070df9d in QSpinBox::valueChanged(int) ()
#7  0x00000001004d9684 in QSpinBoxPrivate::emitSignals(EmitPolicy, QVariant const&) ()
#8  0x000000010043b321 in QAbstractSpinBoxPrivate::setValue(QVariant const&, EmitPolicy, bool) ()
#9  0x000000010043c11a in QAbstractSpinBoxPrivate::_q_editorTextChanged(QString const&) ()
#10 0x000000010043cca7 in QAbstractSpinBox::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) ()
#11 0x000000010070e435 in QSpinBox::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) ()
#12 0x0000000100d09b66 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) ()
#13 0x000000010048a1e6 in QLineEdit::textChanged(QString const&) ()
#14 0x000000010048d23a in QLineEdit::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) ()
#15 0x0000000100d09b66 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) ()
#16 0x000000010070c9f9 in QLineControl::textChanged(QString const&) ()
#17 0x0000000100494337 in QLineControl::finishChange(int, bool, bool) ()
#18 0x0000000100496664 in QLineControl::processKeyEvent(QKeyEvent*) ()
#19 0x000000010048b8eb in QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*) ()
#20 0x00000001001056bd in QWidget::event(QEvent*) ()
#21 0x000000010048c18b in QLineEdit::event(QEvent*) ()
#22 0x000000010043d9f0 in QAbstractSpinBox::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*) ()
#23 0x00000001001056bd in QWidget::event(QEvent*) ()
#24 0x000000010043bb1b in QAbstractSpinBox::event(QEvent*) ()
#25 0x00000001004d7be5 in QSpinBox::event(QEvent*) ()
#26 0x00000001000a9e8d in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
#27 0x00000001000b198b in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
#28 0x0000000100d0321c in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
#29 0x00000001000a9f2c in qt_sendSpontaneousEvent(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
#30 0x0000000100125cc1 in QKeyMapper::sendKeyEvent(QWidget*, bool, QEvent::Type, int, QFlags<Qt::KeyboardModifier>, QString const&, bool, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool*) ()
#31 0x0000000100126b43 in QKeyMapperPrivate::translateKeyEvent(QWidget*, OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, bool) ()
#32 0x000000010006072e in qt_dispatchKeyEvent(void*, QWidget*) ()
#33 0x000000010005478b in -[QCocoaView keyDown:] ()
#34 0x00007fff815a90c7 in -[NSWindow sendEvent:] ()
#35 0x0000000100059891 in -[QCocoaWindow sendEvent:] ()
#36 0x00007fff814ddafa in -[NSApplication sendEvent:] ()
#37 0x000000010005cf0a in -[QNSApplication sendEvent:] ()
#38 0x00007fff814746de in -[NSApplication run] ()
#39 0x0000000100066c04 in QEventDispatcherMac::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
#40 0x0000000100def774 in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
#41 0x0000000100defa94 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
#42 0x0000000100df10bc in QCoreApplication::exec() ()
#43 0x0000000100001cf6 in main ()
```

Comment: `rect` is a member function of `QWidget`: it may crash if you call it before the object is fully constructed. When are you trying to call the function?

Comment: It is after construction of PlotCanvas object, actually it's called inside public member function which is invoked from outside of PlotCanvas object. Also it could be noted that there is no call to getDivCount() in constructor.

Comment: Can you show the code where you construct the object, and also where you call the function?  You say it resides inside another class, but the constructor of that class isn't initializing it...

Comment: I have added the code to the original post. Both are initialized in Board class. It is residing as viewport of QAbstractScrollArea..

Comment: Good... but you still haven't shown where `getDivCount` is called.

Comment: It is called by Board class by it's getDivCount() method. This Board's getDivCount() is invoked by another class when spinbox value is changed. But I think that it doesn't really matter how it is called.

Comment: From the stack trace, you should have shown us the code of the functions `Board::getDivCount()` and `CommonKnobs::updateScaleByBeginEnd()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it sorted out, it was using parent() as pointer to Board (casted with scatic_cast, i thought that cast to wrong object with static_cast would kill it in that point, but no) from PlotCanvas and another class I am using, when actually parent() refereced to PlotCanvasScrollArea in case of PlotCanvas and QGroupBox in case of the other class.
What is strange that debugger shown that I actually jumped into Board's code even thought address of called object was plain wrong and what is even more strange that it crashed in PlotCanvas code not in origin (Board's code).
But now it's ok. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the crash stack trace - does it lead up into the constructor somewhere? My first thought is that I'm not sure you should be calling update inside the constructor - I could be off base, but that seems wrong to me. If update should be called inside a QWidget constructor, then the base constructor will call it (making your call redundant), and if it shouldn't, then I'm not at all clear what's going to happen.

Comment: It is not the case, because widget is displayed correctly, it crashes after doing some gui actions which invokes getDivCount() method. But for peace of mined I have commented it out, nevertheless it still segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollArea is created as a child of plotSplitter, but it is never added to the splitter with addWidget(), in addition plotSplitter has no parent, which means it will be its own window.  I would imagine the problem is probably coming from when you set the viewport of the scrollArea to the plotsCanvas, which is another QWidget with no parent and thus its own window as well.

Try something like this and work from there:

```
Board(QString & name) : name(name)
{
    hbox = new QHBoxLayout();
    commonKnobGroup = new QGroupBox("Common settings:");
    commonKnobGroup->setMinimumWidth(190);
    commonKnobGroup->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum));
    commonKnobs = new CommonKnobs(commonKnobGroup);
    hsplitter = new QSplitter();
    plotGroupBox = new QGroupBox("Measurement plots:", hsplitter);
    settingsGroupBox = new QGroupBox("Plot settings:", hsplitter);
    plotSplitter = new QSplitter(this);
    plotHbox = new QHBoxLayout();
    plotHbox->addWidget(plotSplitter);
    plotGroupBox->setLayout(plotHbox);
    settingsVLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    plotNamesColumn = new QListWidget(plotSplitter);
    scrollArea = new PlotCanvasScrollArea(plotSplitter);
    plotSplitter->addWidget(plotNamesColumn);
    plotSplitter->addWidget(scrollArea);
    //scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
    plotsCanvas = new PlotCanvas(this);
    scrollArea->setViewport(plotsCanvas);
    scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
    specializedKnobGroup = new QGroupBox("Probe settings:");
    plotSettings = new QStackedWidget(specializedKnobGroup);
    settingsVLayout->addWidget(commonKnobGroup);
    settingsVLayout->addWidget(specializedKnobGroup);
    settingsGroupBox->setLayout(settingsVLayout);
    hbox->addWidget(hsplitter);
    setLayout(hbox);
    connect(plotNamesColumn, SIGNAL(currentItemChanged(QListWidgetItem *, QListWidgetItem *)), this,
            SLOT(changePageNames(QListWidgetItem*, QListWidgetItem*)));
    connect(commonKnobs, SIGNAL(scaleUpdated()), plotsCanvas, SLOT(update()));

};
```

Comment: It thought about it, but I can't imagine that it would change it what so ever, because visuall GUI looks the same - so hierarchy of widgets must be the same. But thank you for pointing this out, I thought that just making something parent equals to addWidget call to that parent and vice versa. I have tried this code, but the result is the same :(.. I'm starting to think that I have broken Qt or something...

Comment: Did you also try adding a parent to hsplitter?  Such as hsplitter = new QSplitter(this);  Its a path I would go down because the only reason I can think of for that segfault is rect() is returning zero for some reason and getDivCount() is doing a divide by zero.  So a zero size could have to do with your layouts and widget parents etc.

Comment: Two more things to check: 1) Are you mixing debug and release libraries? That can lead to very weird bugs. 2) Look for buffer overruns elsewhere in the code.  It may be that the bug is somewhere else, and this call just happens to hit a bad point in memory.

Comment: How could I check mixing of libraries? I am using Xcode with set up library lookup path to QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include and QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib/** and I have added frameworks QtGui.framework and QtCore.framework into project framweroks so I'm really not in cotrol which libraries are used..

Comment: and I dug up this in documetation: "First, we create the widgets we want in the layout. Then, we create the QHBoxLayout object and add the widgets into the layout. Finally, we call QWidget::setLayout() to install the QHBoxLayout object onto the widget. At that point, the widgets in the layout are **reparented** to have window as their parent." so I understand that when I add widget to layout I dont's need to state there parent as long as I install layout with setLayout()...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the widget `geometry` instead of the `rect`.  Also be careful of copy constructors.  If you are using member variables, you will need to use setGeometry or setRect instead of copy constructors.

See the [Qt Window Geometry](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/application-windows.html#window-geometry) documentation.